# Алгоритмы. Стенка из блоков

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Имеется неограниченое поле `MxN`. На нём расположены блоки прямоугольной формы `1х1`, `1х2`, `1х3`, `2х2` и т.д. до `8х8`. Количество ограничено. Блоки могут располагаться как вплотную, так и с пробелами.
[Пример](https://ibb.co/h1ubf7) допустимого расположения блоков на поле.
[Пример](https://ibb.co/kp7ZYS) недопустимого расположения блоков.
Поле вводится в виде 0 и 1. Пример ввода для поля с допустимым расположением:

```
101101
111111
111111
```

Задание состоит в том, чтобы определить возможно ли на основе данных блоков построить данную стенку.

Подскажите в какую сторону вообще копать для решения задачи, или с помощью какого алгоритма возможно его добиться.
Я решил для каждой клеточки поля задать вероятность того, что она принадлежит какому-то из блоков. Рассчитал с какой вероятностью какой блок где может находится, начал по очереди подставлять блоки, но фигня какая-то получается...

Comment: Полный перебор, походу...

Comment: Ну не скажите. Для начала можно проверить все клетки стенки может ли там стоять хотя бы один из блоков. Если есть клетка что там нельзя поставить ни один из блоков то полный перебор не потребуется. Ну а иначе перебор. Начинать логичнее с самых крупных блоков я думаю.

Comment: Ну да еще можно для начала посчитать площадь блоков и площадь стенки. Если у стенки площадь больше то явно блоков не хватит.

Comment: https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8E

Comment: "неограниченое поле MxN" - это круто :)

Comment: @Harry я тоже оценил

Answer (score 0):

Напоминает задачу на динамическое программирование. Попробуйте подумать следующим образом:

1. берем левый верхний угол стены и смотрим какие блоки из оставшихся можно положить так, чтобы их край был в этом углу. Если таких блоков нет, то ответ "НЕТ" (решения нет).
2. Если такие блоки нашлись, то для каждого из них решаем эту же задачу с "урезанной стеной" (та, что останется после удаления из нее данного блока, учтите повороты блока) и с меньшим кол-вом оставшихся блоков. Если "урезанная стена" превратилась в пустоту (все нули на поле MxN), то нам удалось построить стену и ответ "ДА". Иначе рекурсия по "урезанной стене" + "остаток блоков" (для каждого блока из п.1).